# dottedcontents problem in the subsection

Tags: table-of-contents

In the first picture, I used only line 1 but dots are not proper while dots in the sections are.

line1 \dottedcontents{section}[0em]{}{2.9em}{0.2pc}

line2  %\dottedcontents{subsection}[3em]{}{2em}{0.2pc}

line3  %\dottedcontents{subsubsection}[4.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}

[image]

In the second picture, I used both line 1 and line 2 and all dots are proper but the page layout is not right. How can I fix this problem? Thank you in advance.

line1  \dottedcontents{section}[0em]{}{2.9em}{0.2pc}

line2 \dottedcontents{subsection}[3em]{}{2em}{0.2pc}

line3 %\dottedcontents{subsubsection}[4.5em]{}{2.5em}{1pc}

[image]

Comment: It don't think it is possible to answer this unless you provide more information. where did you use `\dottedcontents`, how is it defined? it is not defined by any standard class, I see some thesis classes have commands of that name as does titletoc, but with no example code provided hard to say anything

Comment: So sorry, it was an emergency question. It is article class. Because I use a lot of code in this document, I couldn't create MWE. But I'll try to do it.

Comment: `article` class does not define `\dottedcontents`